# Orthanc Server: как различать аппараты?

Tags: linux, dicom

У меня стоит задача: сделать dicom сервер для получения изображений с узи аппаратов. Почитав в интернете, я выбрал Orthanc Server. Установил, настроил и все работает. Но есть один момент, который не могу решить: как различать аппараты?

Возможно, я не верно понял как работает dicom и мне и не надо различать их. Вот как описывается процесс получение снимков [на сайте Orthanc Server](https://book.orthanc-server.com/_images/PS3.4_C.6-1.svg)

Но проблема в том, как различать пациентов?